# Solution to $x''(t)+a(t)x(t)=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Consider everything one dimensional, i.e. I want to find a solution $x:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ to the ODE above with $a:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ at least continuous (you can assume it bounded in case, anyway I'm interested mainly in the solution on compact intervals $[0,T]$ rather than the long time behaviour). Is there a nice way to write the solution explicitly, at least under reasonable assumptions on $a$?

The only case in which I know this can be done it's when $a$ is constant, and in that case the behaviour is radically different depending on the sign of $a$; in general I would prefer not to impose a condition like $a\geq 0$ or $a\leq 0$ for all $t$, but if that helps also a formula in that particular case would be very appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately, this kind of problem would be *very* difficult to solve with any sort of generality. Even a simple case like $a(t) = t$ is not expressible in terms of elementary functions

Comment: This cannot be "solved by quadratures", as they call it.  That is, we cannot find a formula even involving a finite number of indefinite integrations, like the known formula for the linear first-order ODE.

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is essentially not simpler than the general second-order linear ODE
$$y''(t)+p(t) y'(t)+q(t) y(t)=0 \tag{1} .$$
In order to see this, try the substitution
$$y(t)=\mathrm{e}^{-\int p(t)/2 \mathrm{d} t}  x(t).$$

It is well known that equation $(1)$ cannot be solved in the general case.

Comment: Is there a proof that there is no general solution or is it unknown that such a solution exists? I was looking for a reference for such a proof.

Comment: @MrYouMath see the discussion [here](https://youtu.be/tV-xIhP7VU8?t=7m49s).

Comment: It is really worth to watch the whole series. Carl Bender is a fantastic lecturer.

Comment: @user1337: I already watched this series but as far as I remember he did not mention a proof but rather said that a the moment there is no method available.

Comment: @MrYouMath [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Integration_of_differential_equations_in_closed_form) there is a reference by Liouville, showing that the particular case $y''+xy=0$ cannot be integrated using elementary functions. It follows that the more general equation cannot be expressed using elementary functions in the general case.

Comment: @user1337 I didn’t realize that, thank you! even if the function cannot be expressed with elementary functions, is there still some way to express it using series for example?

Comment: @user1337: Thank you for the reference :).

Answer (score 0):

I want to add another remark to why this is difficult in general. One might be tempted to write

\begin{equation}
 \frac{d}{dx}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ \dot x\end{bmatrix} 
 = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-a(t)  &0\end{bmatrix} 
\cdot \begin{bmatrix} x \\ \dot x\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}

And then say that the solution to the time dependent linear system $\dot x = A(t) x$ is simply $x(t)=e^{\int_0^t A(\tau)d\tau}x_0$. **However this formula almost always fails**, since $\frac{d}{dt} e^{B(t)}=\dot Be^{B(t)} $ is only true when $B$ and $\dot B$ commute.

So let $b(t) = -\int a(t)$. Then in the case at hand,  $B = \int A = B_0 + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & t \\ b(t) &0\end{bmatrix}$. Hence the formula is only applicable if $[B,\dot B] =0$, which is a very strong restriction on what $b(t)$ can possibly be.

Comment: Yes I already tried to go down this path, a condition sufficient for it to work is that $A(t)$ and $A(s)$ commute, but that happens only in the $a$ constant case. Thanks anyway!